# How to figure part per 100000

Tags: recurrent-events

I have 39 events in my area.  How do I represent this as 39 events per 100000 people?  I have a city population of about 14400 people.  I divided the number events by the population getting the percentage of the population, but now I need it in events per 100000 people.

Comment: it's not clear what you need. Could you maybe illustrate it with an example?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a simple proportion:

39 events / 14400 people = x events / 100000 people

= 39 / 14400 * 100000

= 270.833 events / 100000 people